# Video editor for Android similar to Premiere Pro

Tags: android, video-editing, android-nougat

I want a video editing app for Android that can do the following:

- Split and trim videos.
- Edit the audio of the video (as muting at certain intervals, increasing and decreasing volume) and add external audio files easily and at the wanted time intervals.
- Step forward or backward one frame (like Adobe's program).
- It is better if it has an easy interface for editing (preferably something like Adobe's timeline).

I know it is less-likely for something like this to be found so please suggest the apps with the nearest features to this.

P.S. : I tried premier clip and it is not what i want.

Edit : If you can recommend 3 or even 4 apps that i can use together and cover most of the features above then go on.

Comment: I don't edit videos on Android devices due to screen estate etc. – but I've got [a list of video editors](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_video#group_229) you might wish to check with while waiting for answers. The full feature set of Premiere Pro won't be there, but there are several good ones available. I didn't try any of them, hence just this comment.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find the perfect app you're looking for - but here's as close as I could get and I couldn't write this in the comments because it's too long :D

I checked out the list in the comment and tried 3 apps -
Timbre: Easy to use and good for splitting videos and trimming, but I lacked the important feature (to me) to put music files on top of the video

FxGuru was definitely for effects mostly (I only watched the advertisement video), so not what I was looking for

**FilmoraGo** was what I personally was looking for: Join, trim videos and put music on top. You can edit pretty small steps (to decimals after a second), but not a single frame I think. Music fades out in the end automatically which was perfect in my case, but if you add transitions be careful cause it will shorten the overall video. Free, no advertising in the finished video or in the program (at least not while I used it). Too many permissions, but I can control individual permissions on my phone so I just blocked most of them and the app still worked :)
They had some (imo bad) themes but fortunately you don't have to use them and some of the transition effects I didn't find too bad. I don't think on a small 5inch android phone screen like mine one can expect something even better unless they're willing to sacrifice user experience and have much more time to kill. But of course I'd be glad if someone can prove me wrong :)

> EDIT: I use **YouCut** nowadays, I like it even more than FilmoraGo
>   It's quite minimalistic but enough for me (cut/trim/join/crop/music) with a clean user experience.

Answer (score 1):

[Kinemaster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nexstreaming.app.kinemasterfree) fits your needs. It's a paid app but it has all the features you need. It is by far the most advanced video editor I've found for android.

- It has a timeline and you can pinch to zoom in the timeline to edit the clip frame by frame.
- Like premier, it has separate audio channels if you want to mute the audio at certain intervals or want to add another audio.
- Trimming is also possible and it is very accurate.